# How can I add data from Points to Polygons (intersected or near) in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, data, intersection

I'm using ArcGIS 10. I have a Point and a Polygon shapefile. The Points have a **NAME** field filled, and the Polygon the same but emptied a minority (350 out of 3000). I need to catch these names from the points only to polygons which have no data in this Field.

Is there any tool, or anything from ArcGIS which offer this solution?
Screenshot att:

Thanks!!

[image: Polygons and Points]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have multiple points for one polygon, you simply need to perform a [spatial join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) and assign the points' names to the respective polygons.

Comment: Thanks very much, very appreciate.
I intended to do it into the same "field" but, all I have to do is Selecting all Null values, then taking the Field Calculator and assign the values from one field to the other. Field1 = [Field2].

Comment: Another problem is as you mentioned, when you have 2 or more Points into one Polygon, but I think this is a bit more complex. Thanks for all @karpfen.